# Convert MSsQL to MySql stored procedure using @variable

Tags: mysql, sql-server, variables, stored-procedures

I used this SP with MsSQL. How do I convert it to MySql?

It would not allow me to create procedure because of syntax errors.

The goal is to receive a string from a user like this:
(ReportId,UserName) - if found in the variable, send back Allowed else send back Access denied.

Thanks.

```
Procedure [dbo].[Permission]
@ReportId   As Int
,@UserName  As Varchar(50)
As
Declare
    @Result As Varchar(250)

Select
    @Result = IsNull((
        Select
            IsNull([permission].[Message], '')

        From
            [permission]
            Join
            [users]
                On [users].[ID] = [permission].[User ID]

        Where
            [users].[User Name] = @UserName
            And [permission].[Report ID] = @ReportId
    ), 'Access denied')


Select
    Case
        When @Result = '' Then 'Allowed'
        Else @Result
    End [Result]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not comprehensive list but:

- Remove `@` symbols, those are for session variables; alternatively, you may want to replace them with some sort of standardized prefixes to prevent potential ambiguity with field names from tables.
- Replace `[` and `]` with `
- `IsNull` becomes `IfNull`
- when doing assignments, like `SELECT @Result = IsNull(...`, change `=` to `:=`

Also, end your statements with `;`, I have no idea why so many MSSQL users love skipping them.

For general create proc syntax, go to [CREATE PROCEDURE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html).

Answer (score 0):

I translated your SP to MySQL Syntax:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE if exists Permission$$
CREATE PROCEDURE Permission(
    p_ReportId   Int,
    p_UserName  Varchar(50)
    )
BEGIN
    set @Result = '';

    set @Result = 
    coalesce(
       (Select
            coalesce(permission.Message, '')
        From permission Inner Join users
            On users.ID = permission.`User ID`
        Where
            users.`User Name` = p_UserName
            And permission.`Report ID` = p_ReportId)
        , 'Access denied');


    Select
        Case
            When @Result = '' Then 'Allowed'
            Else @Result
        End as Result;
END $$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: @joell can you mark my answer as "accepted"? that will helps me to improve my reputation and continue helping stackoverflow users.